# Friends invited to an app not in friends list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've just implemented Request Dialog to invite friends of a logged in person.

It works, a notifications shows up on invited friend's FB page, then this friends click it, and accepts the application.

But then, when I request "/me/friends" on a user who invited someone, this invited user doesn't show up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The friend and the session user need to both have granted `user_friends` permission

> - A user access token with user_friends permission is required to view the current person's friends.
> - This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.
> - If a friend of the person declines the user_friends permission, that friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends

Comment: Thanks, but I am doing it, here is a snippet:   $helper = new Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('https://apps.facebook.com/'.$this->app_id.'/');
  $data['login_url'] = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('email','user_friends','publish_actions'));

Comment: @Konrad then file a bug. As long as both users have granted `user_friends` you should be able to see the friendship.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me with finding a bug - I had two login scripts, on php side and js side, the later was the one in use, and I had no 'user_friends' in scope right there.